# Segmentation fault : Address out of bounds for a pointer in C

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to build and run some complicated code that was written by someone else, I don't know who they are and can't ask them to help. The code reads a bpf (brain potential file) and converts it to a readable ascii format. It has 3 C files, and 2 corresponding header files. I got it to build successfully with minor changes, however now it crashes 
with a segmentation fault.

I narrowed the problem down to FindSectionEnd() (in ReadBPFHeader.c) and find that the error occurs when sscanfLine() (in the file sscanfLine.c) is called (code for both is below).

ui1 is defined as unsigned char. 
si1 is defined as char.

Just before returning from sscanfLine(), the address pointed to by dp is 0x7e5191, or something similar ending with 191. However, on returning to FindSectionEnd(), dp points to 0x20303035 and it says 'Address 0x20303035 is out of bounds', which then causes a fault at strstr(). The loop in FindSectionEnd() runs without problem for 14 iterations before the fault occurs. I have no idea what is going wrong. I really hope the information I have given here is adequate.

```
ui1 *FindSectionEnd(ui1 *dp)
{
    si1 Line[256], String[256];
    int cnt=0;
    while (sscanfLine(dp, Line) != EOF){
        dp = (ui1 *)strstr(dp, Line);
        dp+= strlen(Line);
        sscanf(Line,"%s",String);
        if(SectionEnd(String))
            return(dp);
    }
    return(NULL);
}

si1 *sscanfLine(ui1 *dp, si1 *s)
{
    int i = 0;

    *s = NULL;
    int cnt = 0;
    while (sscanf(dp, "%c", s + i) != EOF){
        cnt++;

        dp++;
        if(*(s + i) == '\n') {
            *(s + i + 1) = '\0';
            return s;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    *(s + i) = '\0';
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Is this C code or C++ code? You don't say and, unfortunately, specified both tags. (The code has no overflow checks. A corrupt input file could easily cause it to misbehave or crash.)

Comment: `*s = NULL;` is probably wrong. Did you mean `s = NULL;`?

Comment: @Named: No, it's fine although a bit confusing.  Most people would write `*s = 0;` or `*s = '\0';`

Comment: You said si and ui are unsigned int and signed int, but this code uses ui1 and si1. What are they defined as?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Now it is updated to si1 and ui1! This is C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sscanfLine` function doesn't respect the size of the buffer passed in, and if it doesn't find `'\n'` within the first 256 bytes, happily trashes the stack next to the `Line` array.

You may be able to work around this by making `Line` bigger.

If you're going to improve the code, you should pass the buffer size to `sscanfLine` and make it stop when the count is reached even if a newline wasn't found.  While you're at it, instead of returning `s`, which the caller already has, make `sscanfLine` return the new value of `dp`, which will save the caller from needing to use `strstr` and `strlen`.

Comment: Awesome! Making Line bigger appears to fix the fault.  I am not looking to improve this code as of now, I just need the output from this code to work on going ahead. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that your string is not null terminated and strstr() segfaults because it reads past the boundaries of the array